# Python function with a argument doesn't work

Tags: python, function, arguments

The code below counts the amount of `"fizz"` in a list and is not working for some reason. It's supposed to return 1 in this case yet it returns 0. This is probably due to some very simple error but I just can't figure it out. Thanks for the help!

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for whatever in x:
        if x == "fizz":
            count += 1
    return count

fizz_count(["fizz","buzz"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you should check here is whatever:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for whatever in x:
        if whatever == "fizz":
            count += 1
    return count

fizz_count(["fizz","buzz"])
```

For debugging I suggest that you try printing stuff inside your function. Like here a simple print(x) would have given you the idea about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a small bug. In your `for` loop, you are comparing the whole iterable/list `x` with `'fizz'`. Change that line to

```
if whatever == 'fizz':
```